# packege not upgrade ubuntu 22.4

Tags: upgrade

[enter image description here][1]

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/X8Sjc.pngerror: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
**Errors were encountered while processing:
/var/cache/apt/archives/folder-color_0.3.0_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
**strong text****

Comment: You've only provided summary details from your messages, read up slightly above what you pasted for more clues (*the error gets summarized again in what you pasted, but the initial messages provide the most detail*).  You don't mention any release but appear to be using 22.04 from the title (*details in the title should also be in your question as not all browser/configs show title when reading the page*) and the package you mention doesn't match `folder-color | 0.0.86-0ubuntu4 | jammy/universe  | source, all` which is expected for a 22.04 system, so please clarify & provide full messages